# Using a rule to match pairs of 2d arrays in a 3d array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider a 3d array of shape (4, 4, 4).  Each 2d array along `axis=0` has a **vertically flipped** match somewhere in the 3d array.
In the small example shown, `arr[0]` and `arr[3]` form a flipped pair, as do `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [3, 3, 3, 3],
                 [4, 6, 0, 9],
                 [4, 3, 2, 1]],
                  
                [[5, 6, 5, 6],
                 [8, 8, 8, 8],
                 [0, 9, 0, 9],
                 [1, 2, 4, 8]],

                [[1, 2, 4, 8], 
                 [0, 9, 0, 9],
                 [8, 8, 8, 8],
                 [5, 6, 5, 6]],

                [[4, 3, 2, 1],
                 [4, 6, 0, 9],
                 [3, 3, 3, 3],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

**QUESTION**:  How can I find the indices of the flipped pairs of 2d arrays?
The output, in the example given, would be:

```
matched_pairs = [[0, 3],
                 [1, 2]]
```

The actual starting 3d array typically has a shape  like (20000, 8, 8), so matched_pairs would be of shape (10000, 2).

Comment: Can matches be anywhere in the array e.g. for your example could the result be `[[0, 1], [2, 3]]` or will they always be in the second half?

Comment: Yes, matching pairs can appear anywhere in the 3d array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `apply_along_axis` together with `lexsort`:

```
a = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x if x[0] < x[-1] else x[::-1], 1, arr)
np.lexsort(a.reshape(a.shape[0], -1).T).reshape(-1, 2)

array([[0, 3],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

---

We could expand this to make it into a generic function:

```
import numpy as np

def get_pairs(arr):
  a = np.arange(np.prod(arr.shape[1:])).reshape(arr.shape[1:])[::-1].ravel()
  def fn(x):
    y = x[a]
    for i,j in zip(x,y):
      if i != j: break
    return x if i<j else y
  b = np.lexsort(np.array([fn(i) for i in  arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], -1)]).T)
  return b.reshape(-1, 2)
  
  
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(5, 4, 5))
b = np.vstack([a, a[:,::-1]])[np.random.choice(10, 10, False)]
d = get_pairs(b)
array([[5, 9],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [6, 7],
       [3, 8]], dtype=int64)

b[d[0]]
array([[[6, 7, 7, 8, 1],
        [7, 6, 8, 8, 1],
        [9, 3, 5, 2, 4],
        [5, 0, 3, 3, 7]],

       [[5, 0, 3, 3, 7],
        [9, 3, 5, 2, 4],
        [7, 6, 8, 8, 1],
        [6, 7, 7, 8, 1]]])
b[d[1]]
array([[[4, 4, 8, 4, 3],
        [7, 5, 5, 0, 1],
        [5, 9, 3, 0, 5],
        [0, 1, 2, 4, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 4, 2],
        [5, 9, 3, 0, 5],
        [7, 5, 5, 0, 1],
        [4, 4, 8, 4, 3]]])
```

---

Time comparison:

```
def pairs_chrslg(arr):
  ii,jj = np.where((arr[None,:,:,:] == arr[:,None,::-1,:]).all(axis=(2,3)))
  m=ii<jj
  return np.array([ii[m], jj[m]]).T

def pairs_nick(arr):
  flip = np.flip(arr, 1)
  matched_pairs = [[i, np.nonzero((arr[i] == flip).all(axis=(1,2)))[0][0]] for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
  return [list(p) for p in {frozenset(p) for p in matched_pairs}]

np.random.seed(0)
def create_arr(n):
  a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(n, 10, 10))
  return np.vstack([a, a[:,::-1]])[np.random.choice(n*2, n*2, False)]

def equal(x, y):
  x = np.array(x)
  x.sort(1)
  y = np.array(y)
  y.sort(1)
  return np.all(x[x[:,0].argsort()] == y[y[:,0].argsort()])

import perfplot
out = perfplot.bench(
    setup= create_arr, 
    kernels=[
        get_pairs,
        pairs_chrslg,
        pairs_nick
    ],
    labels=["onyambu", "chrslg", "nick"],
    n_range=[3, 10, 30, 50, 75, 100, 300, 500, 750, 1000, 1500],
    xlabel="N",
    equality_check=equal
)
out
┌──────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ n    │ onyambu               │ chrslg                │ nick                 │
├──────┼───────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ 3    │ 4.9500000000000004e-… │ 1.25e-05              │ 3.3900000000000004e… │
│ 10   │ 8.2e-05               │ 6.75e-05              │ 0.0001206            │
│ 30   │ 0.0001921             │ 0.0004427             │ 0.00081420000000000… │
│ 50   │ 0.000407700000000000… │ 0.0014860000000000001 │ 0.0019667            │
│ 75   │ 0.0006580000000000001 │ 0.0037497000000000003 │ 0.0040774            │
│ 100  │ 0.0008856000000000001 │ 0.006582800000000001  │ 0.00693480000000000… │
│ 300  │ 0.0030358000000000004 │ 0.06236920000000001   │ 0.060254300000000004 │
│ 500  │ 0.0065998             │ 0.1809316             │ 0.1633378            │
│ 750  │ 0.0083125             │ 0.4043601             │ 0.3742809            │
│ 1000 │ 0.011511700000000001  │ 0.7393738000000001    │ 0.6743115000000001   │
│ 1500 │ 0.018324800000000002  │ 1.7131234000000002    │ 1.7008605            │
└──────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

[image]

---

Note that the other two (expecially Nick's) suffer from memory inefficiency. ie cannot get the pairs for larger arrays. eg (10000, 20, 20)

Comment: Your function def_pairs worked beautifully!  I even applied it to a 3d array of shape (70000, 10, 6), and it found all of the 2d matches in a few seconds.  Big thanks!

Comment: @user109387 just updated the function. Consider using the new function

Comment: The update works great, but I think I prefer the earlier version which gave the 1st column of output in ascending order.  This is important for practical reasons when applied to larger arrays like the (70000, 10, 6) one I tested.

Comment: @user109387 The second version is 2 times the first version. The order is just the final step ie `b[b[:,0].argsort()]` which you can directly include as the last step in the second version. ie save the return value of the second version in a variable eg `c` and then do `return c[c[:,0].argsort()]`.

Comment: This is a really clever use of `lexsort`.

Comment: @Onyambu - yes, I meant to mention that I had included the reordering.   Your revised solution works beautifully and is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

One pure numpy way, using broadcasting, could be

```
ii,jj = np.where((arr[None,:,:,:] == arr[:,None,::-1,:]).all(axis=(2,3)))
```

Explanation:
`arr[None,:,:,:]` is just the array with an extra, len 1 axis, at the beginning, and main axis as `axis=1`, and the 2 matrix axis in pos 2 and 3.
`arr[:,None,::-1,:]` is the array with the extra axis in pos 1, the main axis is pos 0, and the 2 matrix axis in pos 2 and 3.  Plus, the first matrix axis is flipped.
So `arr[None,:,:,:]==arr[:,None,::-1,:]` compares for all pair of position in the main axis (because main axis is 2 different axis in this comparison) the matrices, one of them being flipped. You get a 4D array of booleans, such as `(arr[None,:,:,:]==arr[:,None,::-1,:])[i,j,k,l]` is true iff element `[i,k,l]` of `arr` is the same as its element `[j,-k,l]`.
`.all(axis=(2,3))` checks if it is true for all matrix. So `(arr[None,:,:,:] == arr[:,None,::-1,:]).all(axis=(2,3))[i,j]` is True iff matrix i is matrix j flipped. There should be one True per line
`np.where()` tells where are the "True".

So `ii,jj` are the pairs. You just need to combine them in a single array. Which could be done simply like this

```
np.array(np.where((arr[None,:,:,:] == arr[:,None,::-1,:]).all(axis=(2,3)))).T
```

For the sake of one-liners. But since, to have strictly your wanted output, we need to filter out redundant lines, let's filter ii and jj first, and built the array next

```
ii,jj = np.where((arr[None,:,:,:] == arr[:,None,::-1,:]).all(axis=(2,3)))
m=ii<jj
np.array([ii[m], jj[m]]).T
```

Which returns the exact wanted output.

Timing shows that it is faster than other solutions. (25μs vs 65μs vs 143 μs for original size).

I think (if I understood correctly) that lexsort solution breaks as soon as it find a non-matched value. So, for big array that becomes a clear advantage, probably largely compensating the slowness of `apply_along_axis`. So, for bigger size, Onyanbu's solution would probably win (Edit: I've tested for 100×8×8 array, and we are still even, for 1000×8×8 Onyambu's solution is 10 times faster. Whatever the size, my solution is always faster than Nick's, but with an advantage that reduces in proportion. Only 10% faster for 1000×8×8. Anyway, when I look at it, it is the same solution, only with an explicit `for` instead of a broadcasting implicit one. `::-1` is the `flip`, and my usage of `np.where` with a single argument is synonymous of `nonzero`. But the explicit for avoids the drawback mentioned of my solution in the next sentence)

Plus, my solution has a drawback: it build an N²×W×H boolean array to check a  N×W×H array. For 20000,8,8, it would take some 25 Gb (since 1 boolean = 1 byte in numpy).

Comment: @ chrsig  This gives me  AttributeError:  'bool' object has no attribute 'all'.   I'm hoping there is an easy fix.    Your explanation was very detailed and clearly presented - I learned a lot.  Thanks.

Comment: Which of the 3 lines show this error? I can't reproduce it from your own `arr`. Very probably the 1st one, I suppose (the one with a `all`). Which is what would occur if `(arr[None,:,:,:] == arr[:,None,::-1,:])` was a boolean, and not an array of booleans. So if `==` was taken as the primitive python comparison, not as a `__eq__` method. But that shouldn't happen if arr is as shown in your question. Are you sure `arr` was in the correct form when you tried that? Again, I just copy and paste you `arr=np.array...`, then my 3 lines, and everything works as intended.

Comment: This is a good use of broadcasting to avoid the `flip` in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each element of `arr`, checking if it is equal to another element of `arr` flipped on axis 1:

```
flip = np.flip(arr, 1)
matched_pairs = [[i, np.nonzero((arr[i] == flip).all(axis=(1,2)))[0][0]] for i in range(arr.shape[0])]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]]
```

If you know all pairs are between the first and second half of the array, you can simply iterate just the first half of the array i.e.

```
i in range(arr.shape[0] // 2)
```

Otherwise you can filter duplicates from that list if required:

```
matched_pairs = [list(p) for p in {frozenset(p) for p in matched_pairs}]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [0, 3]]
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution.  This worked well with smaller samples but really struggled when the 3d arrays got deep along axis=0.

Comment: @user109387 np, I was expecting someone to come up with something more efficient, and not disappointed. :) Good question.